# Getting collectionView's HeaderView reference from Indexpath

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am using below code to get collectionView headreView reference by passing selected collection view item's index path but it works only with first item of collection view section.

If I pass second collection view item's indexpath to self.collectionView.supplementaryView it returns nil.

I have no idea why it is failing. Any solution for this would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
self.collectionView.supplementaryView(forElementKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, at: indexPath)
```

Comment: Can you show some additional, relevant code?

Comment: I assume when you ask for the 2nd collection view item's indexpath, the section header is actually visible. If not, it might have been returned to the re-use pool of supplementary views, and could thus be `nil`.

Comment: Thanks for response. CollectionView Header is still visible if I click [0, 0] -> Success and if [0, 1] -> Fail, return nil

Comment: I found the reason why it became nill.. I should be passing section's index path instead of cell item's indexPath. Changing this fixed my problem

Comment: thanks so much @nik, i've been pulling my hair out for 2h already